# Проблема копирования изображения из галереи в папку с приложением. Android

Tags: java, android

При нажатии на кнопку открывается `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);` меню для выбора изображения. После выбора, путь к изображению в галерее сохраняется и изображение устанавливается на ImageView. После перезапуска приложения вытаскиваю путь к изображению через SharedPreferences и оно снова успешно устанавливается на ImageView. Проблема в том, что приложение дает сбой, если пользователь удаляет картинку из галереи или перезапускает устройство (сбивается путь к изображению).

Я решил, что требуемое изображение стоит копировать в папку с приложением и брать путь уже оттуда, но в коде возникла проблема.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageView iv_test, changeBackBtn;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1234;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //загрузка картинки при входе в приложение
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("APP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String uriString = preferences.getString("image_uri", "");
        iv_test = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_test);

        if (uriString != null) {
            try {
                iv_test.setImageBitmap(bitmapFromUri(Uri.parse(uriString)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //если путь сбивается, то на ImageView устанавливается белый фон
                iv_test.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            }
        }

        //кнопка для выбора изображения
        changeBackBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.changeBackBtn);
        changeBackBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            }
        });

    }

    //получение и сохранение пути к изображению
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selected = data.getData();
            iv_test.setImageURI(selected);
            preferences.edit().putString("image_uri", selected.toString()).apply();
        }
    }

    private Bitmap bitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor contentResolver = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptorlet = contentResolver.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptorlet);
        contentResolver.close();
        return image;
    }
```

Код, представленный выше работает, сохраняется путь к изображению с галереи. В `onActivityResult` я попытался добавить код, для копирования изображения в папку с приложением. Но почему-то не распознается метод `copyFile`

```
File source = new File(data.getData().toString());
File destination =  getFilesDir();
try 
{
 FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Как можно исправить мой код?

Answer (score 1):

У `FileUtils` нет метода `copyFile`, есть `copy` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUtils